# merge tiff files into one single tiff file(merged tiff should have n number of pages) in python

Tags: python, image, tiff

I want to merge tiff files into one, but merged file should have n number of pages.

For example  -- if there are 2 tiff files -- file1(2 page) , file2(3 page), so merge file should have 5 pages with all images.

I am new in python, tried below code, but it is not working-

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import TiffImagePlugin

list_file = ['History and Physical 3.tif','History and Physical 5.tif']
with TiffImagePlugin.AppendingTiffWriter("./test.tiff",True) as tf:        
    for tiff_in in list_file:
        with open(tiff_in) as tiff_in:
            im= Image.open(tiff_in)
            im.save(tf)
            tf.newFrame()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `tifftools` python package, either via the command line or in python.  `pip install tifftools`, then, from your command line:

```
tifftools merge input1.tiff input2.tiff output.tiff
```

or from python:

```
import tifftools

input1 = tifftools.read_tiff('input1.tiff')
input2 = tifftools.read_tiff('input2.tiff')
# Add input2 to input1
input1['ifds'].extend(input2['ifds'])
tifftools.write_tiff(input1, 'output.tiff')
```

Unlike using PIL, this will not uncompress and recompress the image data.  It also does NOT update the metadata in the file.  For instance, the PageNumber of each page won't be changed.  You could do that manually (e.g., `tifftools --overwrite --set PageNumber 1,5 --set PageNumber,1 2,5 --set PageNumber,2 3,5 --set PageNumber,3 4,5 --set PageNumber,4 5,5 output.tiff`), but you'll need to inspect the tiff files to make sure the directory layout is what you expect.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `tifftools` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet

```
import os
import tifftools
tiff_files_li=[]
for ti in os.listdir():
    if '.tif' in ti:
        tiff_files_li.append(ti)

tifftools.tiff_concat(tiff_files_li, "output.tiff", overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that AppendingTiffWriter can be used if you don't have a multipage image. So maybe you could try `gdal.merge` which I think works best for your case or maybe `append_images`.